# Controller in ASP.NET MVC3 like CodeIgniter in PHP

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, codeigniter

I am new in ASP.NET MVC3 and I need to know something about it.

Could I make the controller playing / structure like [Code Igniter](http://codeigniter.com/).

Example : 
The Controller Folder : Employee and I make the Controller File Like :

- SalaryController.cs
- EmployeeController.cs
- AbsenceController.cs

I could inject the url like this : http://mysite.com/mymvcapp/EmployeeControllerFolder/MyController/RouteValue..

Could I make it?

Comment: no idea what you want, but its usually a bad idea to try and make a framework just try and act like another because thats what you've used before, embrace the framework for what it is

Comment: Sorry to intercept you, but that's my boss wanted i am just the staff and i thought he's right cause as the development process going the controller could be hundreds or may be thousands.. So they need to be collected in folder and the URL also.. Thx

Comment: Why would you try to implement something as horribly broken as CodeIgniter in ASP.NET MVC framework? It is one of the two worst frameworks in PHP (and I am saying that as PHP developer).

Answer (score 0):

That's called Areas in ASP.NET MVC, you create an area (the first part of the path), then a controller (second part) and finally the action (third part).

But I think you should stick with the regular ASP.NET MVC way of doing things, unless your application need an area (like an admin area), stick with regular controllers and their actions.

Comment: Thx All, So I could inform that to my boss. I thought i miss information about the controller. Glad to hear from you all.